# Cannot read data in Firebase Database an Type Object (Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database structure:

```
-- users:

------ Id:

--------- studentInfo:
```

I want to get a `studentInfo` object and after get its `favList`.

```
        String userUid = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
    studentInfoRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(userUid).child("studentInfo");

    studentInfoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            StudentInfo student = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentInfo.class);

            List<String> mFavRest = student.getFavRestaurants();

            if (mFavRest.contains(restaurantUId)) {
                //do something
            } else {
                mFavRest.add(restaurantUId);

                studentInfoRef.child("favRestaurants").setValue(mFavRest);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

But when I try to get the studentInfo at

```
StudentInfo student = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentInfo.class);
```

I get this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String
```

the full stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.unifood, PID: 30540
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzcc(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzd(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.unifood.activities.RestaurantActivity$7.onDataChange(RestaurantActivity.java:240)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaie.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.zzcta(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

My StudentInfo class:

```
public class StudentInfo {


private String campusId;
private List<String> favRestaurants;
private List<String> favProducts;

public StudentInfo() {
    this.favProducts = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.favRestaurants = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public StudentInfo(String campusId) {
    this();
    this.campusId = campusId;
}

// getters and setters
}
```

**UPDATE**

I cleaned all my users at firabase-database, created a new user to test and all run well :)

Comment: Could you please update your post to include an actual image of your Firebase structure (if you can) and also post the code for `StudentInfo.class`. Thanks

Comment: I can't include image :/ That why I said " users --> Id --> studentInfo". I will post StudentInfo. =]